# Conservation law of ODE from Lie symmetry without variational principle

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, lie-algebras

Usually conservation laws are described for variational problems - if there is some symmetry of action/Lagrangian then the corresponding conservation law is derivable from Noether's theorem.
I am wondering if we have some one-parameter Lie symmetry for some ODE that does not necessarily come from variational principle, can there be made a similar statement about conservation laws?

Consider the following ODE.

$$f'(x) = \omega(x,y(x)) $$

Assume there is a one-parameter Lie symmetry $(\hat{x}(x,y,\varepsilon), \hat{y}(x,y,\varepsilon))$ so that in these new coordinates indeed we have that induced differential equation is of the same form, namely, $\hat{\omega} = \omega$, for all $\varepsilon$ in some neighbourhood of zero.

Does there exist some conserved quantity along solution curves $(x, f(x))$ such that it can be obtained from a given one-parameter Lie symmetry?

If not, are there additional requirements for it to exist (except assuming variational principle).

Answer (score 1):

Do you reject "the equation(s)" as a candidate conserved quantity?  If so, "[first integrals](https://www.math24.net/first-integrals/)".

Some people would take this point of view:  The point of Lie symmetry coordinates is that development of the solution becomes translation in one (new) coordinate direction.  This means that the remaining coordinate(s) become an index in the space of solutions.  On any given solution, these other coordinates are constant.

From this point of view, one may say that [first integral(s)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_of_motion#Integral_of_motion) (which are essentially the other coordinate(s)) are the conserved quantities.

Comment: thanks for the answer and for the help! 1) I am not sure I agree that one of the new (canonical) coordinates is constant along the solution. Conserved quantity satisfies PDE $r_x + \omega r_y = 0$ but canonical coordinate $r$ in which Lie symmetry is not a translation satisfies $\xi r_x + \eta r_y = 0$ where $(\xi, \eta)$ are coordinates of Lie symmetry induced vector field. Can you please expand on what you meant? 2) do you know some algorithms (or references to such algorithms) for given Lie symmetry to compute first integrals?

Comment: @DanielsKrimans : Bluman & Kumei, defn. 2.2.5-1: "A change of coordinates (2.42) [from a one-parameter Lie group of transformations] defines a set of canonical coordinates for the one-parameter Lie group of transformations if, in terms of such coordinates, the group [action] becomes [the first $n-1$ coordinates are constant and the $n$-th coordinate is translated by the group parameter]."  Thm. 2.2.5-3: "For any Lie group of transformations, there exists a set of canonical coordinates such that [the group action] is equivalent to [the translation in the definition just recited]."

Comment: @DanielsKrimans : I would look around in that section of Bluman & Kumei to find the construction of the coordinate transform using the exponential of the group action.

Comment: thanks! This is really helpful